# Angular 2 Dynamic add style to host

Tags: css, angular, typescript, directive, styling

I'd like conditionally add style on host element. e.g

```
:host, :host:focus {
    cursor: pointer;
}

:host .disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: default;
}
```

I have an input parameter @Input() enabled: boolean

P.S.  wrapping my component like `<div [class.disabled]="!enabled">  </div>`
is not enough.

I'd like to disable/enable host element.

Comment: `disabled` can only work on specific element like `select`, `input`, `button`

Comment: Hmm, disabled is my custom css style. I can rename it, but it should work. At this moment i don't know how to add my custom css class on host conditionally

Comment: Could you share more HTML code please

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ElementRef` with `Renderer`:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
class YouComponent implements OnChanges {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.hasOwnProperty('enabled')) {
      this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', {isAdd: !!changes['input'].currentValue});
    }
  }
}
```